# Как создать экран загрузки в libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Немного поискав, понял что для этого нужен AssetManager. Но у меня не получилось загрузить Texture с его помощью.

```
AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();
manager.load("rubl.png",Texture.class);
Texture moneta = manager.get("rubl.png",Texture.class);
```

Подскажите как правильно пользоваться AssetManager и что нужно будет делать дальше: создавать отдельный класс, скрин или что-то ещё?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://goo.gl/GZBXvw Пример экрана загрузки 
https://goo.gl/XKzHbP Пример менеджера ресурсов 
Идею где то списал, но к сожалению не помню где

```
@Override
public void show() {
    // Загрузка самого необходимого
    CRAssetManager.getInstance().load("progress_bar.png", Texture.class); 
    CRAssetManager.getInstance().load("progress_bar_base.png", Texture.class);
    // ждем окончания загрузки
    CRAssetManager.getInstance().finishLoading(); 
    // Этими ресурсами уже можно пользоваться
    progressBarBaseImg = CRAssetManager.getInstance().get("progress_bar_base.png"); 
    progressBarImg = CRAssetManager.getInstance().get("progress_bar.png");
// Остальное на загрузку
    CRAssetManager.getInstance().load("background.jpg", Texture.class);
    CRAssetManager.getInstance().load("title.png", Texture.class);
    CRAssetManager.getInstance().load("gameover.png", Texture.class);
    ...
    CRAssetManager.getInstance().load("istrebitel1.png", Texture.class);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    // Отрисовка прогрессбара
    batch.draw(progressBarBaseImg, 10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - progressBarBaseImg.getHeight() / 2,
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 20, progressBarBaseImg.getHeight());
    batch.draw(progressBarImg, 10, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - progressBarImg.getHeight() / 2,
            (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 20) * CRAssetManager.getInstance().getProgress(), progressBarImg.getHeight());
    // CRAssetManager.getInstance().getProgress() - даст нам значение сколько ресурсов уже загружено в интервале от 0 до 1
    batch.end();

    // Если загрузка завершилась перехожу на другой экран
    if (CRAssetManager.getInstance().update()) {
        ScreenManager.getInstance().show(CustomScreen.WELCOME_SCREEN);
    }
}
```